# Omnipascal with Pascal Language Basics not working together

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, omnipascal

When installing Omnipascal VsCode extensions and Pascal Language Basics
extension, the latter wont work. Any ideas why? I would like to have the syntax highlighting from Pascal Language Basics and the navigation, building, suggestions, etc. from Omnipascal.

Thank you in advance!